# Moment js not adding hours and minutes to a specific time

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have a start time to which i would like to add an end time to.
for example

```
startTime=19:09
endTime=00:51 // 0 hours and 51 minutes
```

i want to add the 51 minutes to the 19:09 to make it 20:00.

I have tried multiple different scenarios as showing bellow but nothing is giving me the correct time

i tried

```
let [hour, minute] = endTime.split(':').map(Number);
this.endTime = Moment(startTime)).add({ hour: 'hours', minute: 'minutes' }) // also tried .add(hour,'hours').add(minute,'minutes')
```

which still outputs 19:09. its just ignoring my end time

i tried

```
Moment(endTime, 'hh:mm').add(Moment.duration(startTime)).format("hh:mm");
```

which gives me an output of 08:00 when it should be 20:00

What am i doing wrong?
i want to add the end time to a start time.
Keep in mind that my endTime is always changing so sometimes it could be 13:05 etc cause its a user input

Comment: Try `.format("HH:mm")` with capital `HH` for 00-23 rather than `hh` for 00-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three major issues with your code:

1. Creating a moment with a timestamp alone (ie something like `moment('19:09')` without a date) like you do is deprecated and throws an error. You either have to pass in a fully specified timestamp in RFC2822 or ISO format or explicitely tell the library, what input format you are using.
2. The object you are passing to the `add()` function literally is

   ```
   {
     hour: "hours", 
     minute: "minutes"
   }
   ```

   ie, instead of passing the numerical values for hours and minutes to add to your
   moment, you are passing the strings `"hours"` and `"minutes"`, which obviously
   momentsjs can't handle.
3. The format `hh:mm` only accepts hours from `0` to `12`. If you want a 24-hour clock you have to use `HH:mm`

Taking these issues into account, the following snippet works as expected:

```js
let start = '2021-01-07 19:09', 
    duration = '0:51', 
    starttime = '19:09';

let [hour, minute] = duration.split(":");

//shorthand initialization for the argument
let endtime1 = moment(start).add({hour, minute}).toString(); 

//explicit definition of property names
let endtime2 = moment(start).add({hours: hour, minutes: minute}).toString(); 

//add hours and minutes separately
let endtime3 = moment(start).add(hour, "hours").add(minute, "minutes").toString(); 

//provide a format for the timestamp. momentsjs will take the current date for the date value
let endtime4 = moment(starttime, "HH:mm").add(hour, "hours").add(minute, "minutes").toString();

console.log(endtime1);
console.log(endtime2);
console.log(endtime3);
console.log(endtime4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Also keep in mind, that for specifiying which part of the timestamp to manipulate, you can either use singular or plural wording. Ie

`moment(...).add(4, "hour").add(17, "minute")` and `moment(...).add({hour: 4, minute: 17})`

is equivalent to

`moment(...).add(4, "hours").add(17, "minutes")` and `moment(...).add({hours: 4, minutes: 17})`

respectively as can also be seen in the snippet with the creation of `endtime1` and `endtime2`

Comment: thank you so much!! this was driving me crazy. its working now

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your duration into a single unit as `minutes`, `seconds`, `days` etc...
Then you can use the following snippet to add duration.

[you can uses `moment` methods to convert your duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/)

`const mins = moment.duration(10, "hour").asMinutes();`

```js
const someTime = moment('19:09',"HH:mm");

const data = someTime.add('51','minutes').format("HH:mm")

//More clever solution would be
const data2 = someTime.add(1, "hours").add(51, "minutes").format("HH:mm")
console.log(data)
console.log(data2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```